# Javascript Function For Clipboard copy not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty new at coding in Javascript. I am trying to Copy my url through the action of button click which will fire the function below `CopyTextFunction()`. But I am not being able to find out why it is not working since `alert(copyText);`  in my function shows that the text was copied.

```
function CopyTextFunction() {
                const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                params.get('ID')
                var copyText = "http://randomsite.com/OnlineShop/ShopProducts?ID=" + params.get('ID');
                //alert(copyText);
                alert(copyText);
                navigator.clipboard
                  .writeText(copyText)
                  .then(() => {
                      alert("successfully copied");
                  })
                  .catch(() => {
                      alert("something went wrong");
                  });
            }
```

Comment: "_`alert(copyText);` in my function shows that the text was copied_" Nope, it just alerts the value of `copyText` variable. Remove `catch` and you'll see the error message in the console.

Comment: got this error `NotAllowedError: Document is not focused.`

Comment: A programmatic click is not allowed, `navigator.clipboard.writeText` requires real user interaction.

Comment: It looks like it's `alert` causing the error (with a real click too). When you click OK on the alert box, the script continues before the actual page gets the focus back. Use `console.log(copyText);` instead of `alert`, that makes your code to work.

Comment: @Teemu this solution was terrific.. Thank you so much

Comment: but @Teemu its working on my localhost but not in the live server

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard "_This permission must be obtained from the Permissions API using ..._"

Answer (score -2):

May you should check Browser compatibility for `clipboard.writeText`. I mean... writing permissions for Clipboard depends on browser versions and contexts. Please, have a look to ***** marks in the link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API#browser_compatibility